# Is >= working for comparing date variables?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm filtering on the created property which is a datetime variable comparing it to a date variable. Will >= work here since I'm looking for all the orders including the startdate?

```
orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =',
                        person.key.id()).filter('created >',
                        startdate)
```

So if I'm correct then what I should be doing is

```
orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =',
                        person.key.id()).filter('created >=',
                        startdate)
```

Is the above change allowed / recommended? It seems to work for datetime but when I try it with the data variable I get an error message.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try that and its not working?

Comment: @Shay Erlichmen Maybe I'm doing it wrong but I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` when I try the `<=` filter with the above code. It might have something to do with that I'm doing it for a date and not a datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google App Engine SDK](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py#1525) and [NDB](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#1623) implementation shows that Datetime are represented as `int64` in the datastore, so `>=` filter should works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I could not get it to work. I'm comparing a date object with the datetime variable and I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: And also please the full traceback.